# Word for describing process of walking, going on foot

Tags: word-usage, synonyms

I’m translating an article about a wax-doll museum, and I got trapped on a phrase:

> This wax doll has a mechanism, which simulates {**insert**: *process of going on foot, walking* — something like that}.

I know this is a rather strange construction, but is there a good, maybe a little bit scientific term for describing such an activity?

I was adviced with the word *gait*, but I don't think it suits. Does it describe only a manner of a human walking (or that of a dog, horse), or it can also be used to mean walking itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merriam-Webster defines the word *gait* as “a manner of walking or moving on foot” and typically refers to specific characteristics of the way a person walks.  If you use this word, you should use a modifier like Aaron K suggested.

Of course, which phrase you use depends upon your audience and the purpose of the writing, but I would keep it simple and simply use *walk*.

> This wax doll has a mechanism which simulates **walking**.

Comment: I totally support that "...which simulates walking." would be best in almost every circumstance.  I had included it and deleted it when I realized that it was already in the question.  But sometimes the most obvious answers are best.  *Ambulation* is almost cringe worthy and unless there is something truly remarkable about the simulation, I wouldn't say more than walking.

Comment: No, Merriam-Webster defines the word 'gate' as  “an opening in a wall or fence” or  “a city or castle entrance often with defensive structures”. -1 !

Comment: @jwpat7, Good catch.  I my haste, I confused homophones.  Gate and Gait are not the same word.

Answer (score 4):

A more scientific word would be *ambulation*.

> ambulation: the action of walking, moving about.

As in: "...has a mechanism which simulates ambulation."

If you want to use *gait* you need to say what kind of gait is simulated:

"which simulates a natural gait." or "which simulates a human gait."

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

> This wax doll has a [**walking mechanism**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mechanism%20that%20simulates%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1999,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en).

Comment: Having a mechanism that simulates walking is not necessarily the same as having a walking mechanism.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Aren't all walking mechanisms in dolls mechanisms that simulate walking, as long as dolls, by definition don't walk as we humans do?